# Change PAGE background (not element BG) on any element hover.

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, hover, element

I've been trying to change my PAGE background whenever I hover over an element. Currently I've uploaded different images into my web server, I would like to change my page background from one of the images, to another image when I hover over a div. How would I go about doing this? It doesn't matter if it's javascript, jquery, or css, the more answers the better so that I could learn a new way to do this :)

My css:

```
body{
background: url(../html/dest/back2.png);  
height: 100% ; 
background-attachment:   fixed;
}
```

I have uploaded a new image called back2a.png. I would like to load this image in place of my previous image (back2.png) whenever the user hovers over an element. (Any element) 
Note: I would also like to maintain the background-attachment:fixed on the new image. 
The new image is simply a change of hue/saturation done in photoshop, nothing drastic it's the same size and everything.

Here is the page I'm trying to do this on.
http://hourtimeagent.com/html/c++.php
I appreciate answers! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## jQuery:

```
$("div").hover(function() {
   $("body").css("background", "url(../html/dest/back2a.png)");
});
```

If you want to change it back afterwards you can use the jQuery .blur method:

```
$("div").blur(function() {
   $("body").css("background", "url(../html/dest/back2.png)");
});
```

The div selector can be changed to anything you want it to be on hovering. For example, if you have a div with the id of hover, use something like this:

```
$("div#hover").hover(function() {
   $("body").css("background", "url(../html/dest/back2a.png)");
});
```

Or a class of hover:

```
$("div.hover").hover(function() {
   $("body").css("background", "url(../html/dest/back2a.png)");
});
```

## Javascript

To use straight javascript you'd have to add events to the elements on your page that you want to change the background with. I'd stick with jQuery as it does it for you, but if you'd prefer to use just javascript on a div you'd add:

```
<div onhover="myFunc();"></div>
```

And then the javascript would look like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function myFunc() {
   document.body.style.background = "url(../html/dest/back2a.png)";
</script>
```

Comment: MAN thank you so much! I actually prefer it that it stays different once the link is hovered over. Thank you so much!! :))

Comment: Question, do you know I would be able to prevent that white flash every time the image changes?

Comment: For some reason it does it in chrome but not in IE. Wierd.